# too many jsp files in spring

Tags: spring, jsp, separation-of-concerns

This is a hypothetical question as in i haven't encountered it yet but i'm very curious about it. What if I had **100 jsp files** (it is a big web application) how can i separate my jsp files? What is the suggested practice in this kind of situation? I mean, if i put my jsps under the web-inf, wouldn't the project be bloated? so can i put my jsps in another project and then reference it? I couldn't find anything on the web, all of them described putting all jsps under the web-inf folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you put your JSPs within WEB-INF, then it won't be accessed
  directly by entering the url in the browser.
- By putting your JSP in WEB-INF, you can access that JSP only from other servlet of JSP by request dispatching or forwarding.

You cannot do

```
 www.someSite.com/WEB-INF/somePage.jsp
```

but if you put your somePage.jsp in root folder, then you can access by

```
 www.someSite.com/somePage.jsp
```

For separation of concerns, You can separate according to modules and the type also.

- If some of your pages are just headers and footers, then put them in folders called header and footer
- If some of your pages are related to one Shopping module, then put in shopping module and likewise for other modules.

Comment: I think its a bad design to be able to access JSP directly. The controller should take care of forwarding url to jsp internally with letting the user know which jsp is used.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to tell the difference between those two :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bifurcate files you can put them in different folders, that how it is done. For example all functionality related to finance can be kept in finance folder.